# I set the key in the map but unique key error still exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

```
<MenuList width={'148px'} >
    { Object.entries(userRoleMenu[UserRole]).map((item, index) => <>
        {item[0]==='fpv?
        <MenuItem _hover={{backgroundColor:'gray.50'}} key={item[0]} onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}>
        </MenuItem>
        :
        <MenuItem _hover={{backgroundColor:'gray.50'}} key={item[0]} onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}>{item[0]}</MenuItem>
        }
        </>)
    }
</MenuList>
```

Error:

```
UserProfileThumbnailMenuList.tsx:65 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Check the render method of `UserProfileThumbnailMenuList`.

[See for more information](https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys)
at UserProfileThumbnailMenuList

Code is in: `UserProfileThumbnailMenuList`

I don't know why unique key error still exists.

Comment: Setting key is not enough. Each key should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <MenuList width={'148px'}>
  {Object.entries(userRoleMenu[UserRole]).map((item, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={item[0]}>
      {item[0] === 'fpv' ? (
        <MenuItem _hover={{ backgroundColor: 'gray.50' }} onClick={() => handleMenuClick(item)}>
          {/* Add content for the fpv case here */}
        </MenuItem>
      ) : (
        <MenuItem _hover={{ backgroundColor: 'gray.50' }} onClick={() => handleMenuClick(item)}>
          {item[0]}
        </MenuItem>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</MenuList>
```

I've added the correct key prop to the React.Fragment, and I've also fixed the syntax error in the conditional check by changing {item[0]==='fpv? to {item[0]==='fpv' ?. Make sure to replace the placeholder comment with the actual content for the fpv case inside the MenuItem.

Comment: key to  fragment worked

Answer (score 0):

This error is occur because you use `<> ... </>` react fragment in this way which react don't apply key on it.

You should do this instead:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
.
.
.


<MenuList width={'148px'} >
        { Object.entries(userRoleMenu[UserRole]).map((item, index) => 
<Fragment key={index}>
          {item[0]==='fpv?
          <MenuItem _hover={{backgroundColor:'gray.50'}} onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}>
          </MenuItem>
          :
          <MenuItem _hover={{backgroundColor:'gray.50'}} onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}>{item[0]}</MenuItem>
          }
          </Fragment>)
        }
      </MenuList>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your `key` is not unique, since you `.map` and set the same key for every element created.

You need to change `key={item[0]}` to `key={index}`, or if your `item` element is an object and has a unique identifier, like an `id`, you could do something like `key={item.id}`

Also, you don't need to specify the element and the index `item[0]`, while the `item` contains the exactly element index of the array returned from `Object.entries(userRoleMenu[UserRole])` since `map` take care of it.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

You should make the following changes:

```
<MenuList width={"148px"}>
  {Object.entries(userRoleMenu[UserRole]).map((item, index) =>
    item === "fpv" ? (
      <MenuItem
        _hover={{ backgroundColor: "gray.50" }}
        key={index}
        onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}
      />
    ) : (
      <MenuItem key={index} onClick={handleMenuClick(item)}>
        {item}
      </MenuItem>
    )
  )}
</MenuList>
```